# Complexity of binary search and unique function

Tags: time-complexity, unique, binary-search

I have a question regarding binary search. I know that binary search complexity is log(n). The fact is that I have a binary search algorithm and in between I call a function unique(my_array) that returns the same data as in my_array, but with no repetitions. The size of my_array is m.

Then, i the complexity of my binary search algorithm m.log(n)?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide relevant code, preferably, a minimal working example. The time complexity also depends on the algorithm used to find unique elements.

Comment: If you call `unique` in between binary search then yes time complexity will be `m.lg(n)`. Though, why do you need to call `unique(my_array)` in between, if `my_array` does not change the `unique` will return same result each time, you can call it just once and use it. May be if you could provide more detail about your use case then it will be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you James Mchugh. The unique algorithm that I am using has O(n) according to the documentation.  Vikash Kesarwani, thank you for your answer. I am  calling unique in between because I am performing the binary search, not in the array, but in a parameter that generates an array at each iteration.